# Can anyone suggest how to record audio from microphone on a website using html5 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser, audio-recording

I want to record audio using javascript and html5, there is device element in html5 but i dont know to use it. Found no examples for the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[No current stable browser supports](http://caniuse.com/#search=Stream%20API) the Stream API (formally known as `<device>`), so in practical terms — you can't. The lack of examples using it is a consequence of this.

If you want to play with it, you have to use development branches of Chrome. There is [a demo of voice input here](http://www.filosophy.org/2011/03/talking-to-the-web-the-basics-of-html5-speech-input/).

Comment: @David... Thanks for the link of the demo you gave.. Its pretty cool... So i have to do it flash or java based then..

Answer (score 1):

currently, there are three ways to do it

1. as `wav`
   all code client-side, uncompressed recording], you can check out --> http://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs
2. as `mp3`    [ all code client-side, compressed recording], you can check out --> http://github.com/Mido22/mp3Recorder
3. as `opus packets`    [ client+ server(`node.js`) code, compressed recording], you can check out --> http://github.com/Mido22/recordOpus

Answer (score 0):

A quick search returned https://labs.ericsson.com/developer-community/blog/beyond-html5-audio-capture-web-browsers, which contains the `device` element you mentioned.

Comment: The device tag deprecated.