# Send live voice or sound in a webserver

Tags: javascript, audio, chat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone suggest how to record audio from microphone on a website using html5 and javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058242/can-anyone-suggest-how-to-record-audio-from-microphone-on-a-website-using-html5)

I want to know how voice chat work ? How to record voice by javascript by using microphone in my PC and how to send it in server ? I want to learn how those happened, step by step. Please help me, how should i learn and from where ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cant be done at this point, at least not through javascript alone.

It can be done with JAVA, Silverlight or Flash help.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065797/how-to-record-voice-files-using-php-flash) link.

Or directly [here](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery).